# Using arrays to compare user provided values

Tags: arrays, lua

So I have 3 user-provided values, the first is their "total_income", the second value is either "part_time" or "full_time", and the last value is "family_size".

I'm trying to write code in LUA that takes these values and evaluates them to assign a value called "fee".

I have an excel file that gives me "fee" values for both "full_time" and "part_time", and those depend upon what "total_income" is entered.

The problem I am having is, I don't know how to incorporate the user's provided values of "part_time" and "family_size"

I hope this makes sense, if not please don't hesitate to email me at ochow0401@gmail.com, or PM me here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Whoever can steer me in the right direction first, gets lunch on me ;)

I was able to successfully compare the user-provided "total_income" against the excel file to see where it falls in the income range. Based on this index I am able to see what "fee" value to assign. The code I provided below successfully sets the "fee" for the users "total_income", but how would I do a check for whether the user inputted "part_time" or "full_time" within a loop?

```
part_time_fee = 0
full_time_fee = 0

part_time = {31,38,45,53,68,76,85,94,104,113,123,134,145,156,159,161,164,167,178,181,184,187,190,193,196,199,203,206,209,212,215,218,221,227,234,240,246,252,259,265
}

full_time = {61,75,90,106,135,152,170,207,226,246,267,289,311,317,322,328,334,355,361,367,373,380,386,392,398,405,411,417,423,429,436,442,454,467,479,492,504,517,529
}

family_size_1_or_2 = {2451,2514,2577,2640,2703,2766,2829,2892,2955,3017,3080,3143,3206,3269,3332,3395,3457,3520,3583,3646,3709,3772,3835,3897,3960,4023,4086,4149,4212,4275,4337,4400,4463,4589,4715,4840,4966,5092,5218,5343
}

for i = 1, 40, 1
do
  if family_size_1_or_2[i] >= answers.calc_total_income then
  answers.fam_fee = part_time[i]
  break
  end
end
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OhgT.jpg

That is the first 15 rows of the excel sheet I was provided.

I am to take the users inputs, "total_income", "family_size", and "part_time" or "full_time". Then I am to give it it's corresponding "fee" value.

So if a user were to enter these values:

total_income = 3000
family_size = 2
full_time

then

fee = 226

Comment: why not simply double the fee for full time? what's the point of a second table? I also plotted a few income values to a graph. It's linear. so what is the point of having all those tables? you could simply calculate the fees.

Comment: It's "Lua" not "LUA"..,